# Socket communication between two machines with SFML

Tags: c++, sockets, sfml

I am writing network communication application using sockets and UDP. So far I was able to run both client and server on this same machine, but right now I wanted to move to two separate ones. Most of the communication code used is based on the examples provided with SFML library, yet I cannot connect between machines. Whenever I try to connect computers by providing IP and port there is no response from server at all. This is my code for server:

```
std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> startUdpServer()
{
    std::cout << "Local address: ";
    std::cout << sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress().toString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Public address: ";
    std::cout << sf::IpAddress::getPublicAddress().toString() << std::endl;
    // Create a socket to receive a message from anyone
    std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> socket(new sf::UdpSocket());

    // Listen to messages on the first free port
    if(socket->bind(sf::Socket::AnyPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return nullptr;
    std::cout << "Server is listening to port " << socket->getLocalPort() << ", waiting for a message... " << std::endl;
    return socket;
}

std::pair<sf::IpAddress, unsigned short> runUdpServer(std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> socket)
{
    // Wait for a message
    char in[128];
    std::size_t received;
    sf::IpAddress sender;
    unsigned short senderPort;
    if (socket->receive(in, sizeof(in), received, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "Connection error" << std::endl;
        return std::make_pair(sender, senderPort);
    }
    std::cout << "Message received from client " << sender << ": \"" << in << "\"" << std::endl;
    return std::make_pair(sender, senderPort);
}

void sendUdpMessage(std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> socket, std::pair<sf::IpAddress, unsigned short> config,
                    std::string message)
{
    // Send an answer to the client
    const char* out = message.c_str();
    if (socket->send(out, sizeof(char) * message.length(), config.first, config.second) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the client: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

and client:

```
std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> startUdpClient()
{
    // Ask for the server address
    sf::IpAddress server;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Type the address or name of the server to connect to: ";
        std::cin  >> server;
    }
    while (server == sf::IpAddress::None);

    unsigned short port;
    std::cout << "Type the port number: ";
    std::cin >> port;

    // Create a socket for communicating with the server
    std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> socket(new sf::UdpSocket());

    sf::Packet packet;
    // Send a message to the server
    const char out[] = "Hi, I'm a client";
    if (socket->send(out, sizeof(out), server, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return nullptr;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the server: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;
    return socket;
}

void runUdpClient(std::shared_ptr<sf::UdpSocket> socket, Buffer<std::string>& value)
{
    // Receive an answer from anyone (but most likely from the server)
    char in[256];
    std::size_t received;
    sf::IpAddress sender;
    unsigned short senderPort;
    if (socket->receive(in, sizeof(in), received, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    value.emplace_back(in);
}
```

What I can do to make it work? Any ideas?

**EDIT #1:**

As pointed out, I've forgotten to mention what system I am using. Currently both are Windows, but I am planning to use all of the systems in different combinations (as far as I am aware for sockets it doesn't matter what OS is communicating with which).

Comment: Check your firewall settings on both machines. You forgot to mention what platform you are on. In Ubuntu Linux for example you might need to open your required ports on the `ufw` firewall command.

Comment: @rlam12 Thank you for pointing out lack of information about OS. I've updated question. Is there any way to do it automatically? I just don't want my user configure ports by himself before using application. Also, I am using `sf::Socket::AnyPort` so I don't have hardcoded port number.